# Details page JavaScript through JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to develop an application that when a user searches for a phone they will get some results for example. I type in Samsung , I will get a bunch of Samsung phones which will display the information such as name of the phone and the picture. There will be a "More Info" button towards the bottom. This will be done via JavaScript and an external JSON file.

When the user clicks on the More info button it should take them to a new page displaying all the relevant information for that phone.

I'm just not sure how to do the last part.

**JSON :**

```
  [
      { "name":"Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge+",
        "year":2015,
        "manufacture":"Samsung",
        "description":"Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge+ is an Android smartphone manufactured and marketed by Samsung Electronics. The S6 line serves as a successor to the Galaxy S5. The S6 and S6   Edge smartphones were officially unveiled in the first Samsung Unpacked 2015 event at Mobile World Congress on 1 March 2015, while the bigger S6 Edge+ was officially unveiled together with the Samsung Galaxy Note 5 in the second Samsung Unpacked 2015 event at New York on 13 August 2015. Alongside the S6, Samsung also unveiled the S6 Edge (and later on the bigger S6 Edge+), a variant whose screen is wrapped along the sides of the device; the curvature is usable for several additional features. The Galaxy S6 and S6 Edge were released on 10 April 2015 in 20 countries while the S6 Edge+ was released on 21 August 2015 in 20 countries.",
        "avatar": "https://images.carphonewarehouse.com/is/image/cpw/mobiles/medium/SAMSUNG-GALAXY-S6-EDGE-PLUS-32GB_GOLD_1?wid=232&hei=348",
        "lat": 53.645792,
        "lng":  -1.785035,
        "imgPath": "assets/img/s6Edge+.jpg"},
 ]
```

**Javascript :**

```
    $(window).load(function(){
    $('#search').keyup(function(){
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
        var output = '<div class="row">';
        var count = 1;
        var error = "";
        $.getJSON('assets/js/phones.json', function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(key, val){                
           if ((val.name.search(regex) != -1))       {
              output += '<div class="col-md-6 well">';
              output += '<div class="col-md-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="'+val.imgPath+'"/></div>';
              output += '<div class="col-md-7">';
              output += '<h5>' + val.name + '</h5>';
              output += '<h5><a href=""> More Info</a></h5>';
              output += '</div>';
              output += '</div>';
              if(count%2 == 0){
                output += '</div><div class="row">'
              }
              count++;
              }
          });
if (searchField === "") {
    return false;
} 
          output += '</div>';
          $('#results').html(output);
        });
    });
  });
```

Any immediate help will be highly appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: In what ways does what you have done not work for you (what is the actual question, other than "give me some code"?)

Comment: https://selene.hud.ac.uk/u1262813/practice_1/index.html If you follow that link and type in Samsung you will see what I mean, I don't just want the code, I just need some help on how to do this as I am new to JavaScript. @Soren

Comment: But you have not detailed how or why the code you have doesn't work -- Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have not done any code for that because I don't know how to start it. @Soren

Comment: In that case -- there are too many possible answers for this to be a good question

Comment: @Soren Well can u at least point me to the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the link the example JSON you provide, what should be the detail page link? Do you have this already? If so you can set the href="" of the More info to be it.

Assuming you have a property in the JSON with the full link, e.g.

```
[
      { 
        "name":"Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge+",
        ...
        "link": "/myrelativelink_to_produt.html"
        },
 ]
```

You can change your JS line with the link to:

```
 output += '<h5><a href="' + val.link + '"> More Info</a></h5>';
```

If you don't have a link, you'll probably have to construct it out of whatever data it requires to display the details of the product, with that I cannot help.

But the hint is in setting the href of the a tag, heck it could even be a link to samsung's site :)

Hope this helps,
P.

Comment: I have used a bit of your example, however when I use the variable "link" in the JS file all i get is undefined. Any reason why?

Comment: Yes, because a link property is not defined on your json. You cant make an omelette without eggs. You'll need to figure out how to build the product detail url.

Answer (score 0):

**First Thing :** Pass some unique ID in your JSON Object for each handset.
**Second Thing :** No need to get all data in home page if you only want to display handset name. Just get only `id` and `name` from the api.

**Home Page JSON :**

```
[
      { "id":"1",
        "name":"Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge+"
      },
      { "id":"2",
        "name":"Samsung Galaxy S5"
      },
      { "id":"3",
        "name":"Samsung Galaxy S3"
      }]
```

**Third Thing :** Pass this particular `id` of handset to next page when click on the `more info` option and then based on that id get all the information from the api of the phone associated with that id.

**JSON should be like this :**

```
[
      { "year":2015,
        "manufacture":"Samsung",
        "description":"Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge+ is an Android smartphone manufactured and marketed by Samsung Electronics. The S6 line serves as a successor to the Galaxy S5. The S6 and S6   Edge smartphones were officially unveiled in the first Samsung Unpacked 2015 event at Mobile World Congress on 1 March 2015, while the bigger S6 Edge+ was officially unveiled together with the Samsung Galaxy Note 5 in the second Samsung Unpacked 2015 event at New York on 13 August 2015. Alongside the S6, Samsung also unveiled the S6 Edge (and later on the bigger S6 Edge+), a variant whose screen is wrapped along the sides of the device; the curvature is usable for several additional features. The Galaxy S6 and S6 Edge were released on 10 April 2015 in 20 countries while the S6 Edge+ was released on 21 August 2015 in 20 countries.",
        "avatar": "https://images.carphonewarehouse.com/is/image/cpw/mobiles/medium/SAMSUNG-GALAXY-S6-EDGE-PLUS-32GB_GOLD_1?wid=232&hei=348",
        "lat": 53.645792,
        "lng":  -1.785035,
        "imgPath": "assets/img/s6Edge+.jpg"},
 ]
```